# Why there need memory order limit on reference counter?

Tags: c++, boost, atomic, memory-model, refcounting

In the example of `boost::atomic`, the `unref` function:

```
void intrusive_ptr_release(const X * x)
{
  if (x->refcount_.fetch_sub(1, boost::memory_order_release) == 1) {
    boost::atomic_thread_fence(boost::memory_order_acquire);
    delete x;
  }
}
```

1: the fetch_sub op is limited by **memory_order_release**, which prevents preceding operations to be reordered past the point. But what are the possible scenes that would have such phenomenon?

2: in addition of **memory_order_release** on the atomic op, why there is an additional **memory_order_acquire** before the deletion?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179938/c11-memory-order-acquire-and-memory-order-release-semantics

Comment: This one seems better related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268737/c11-atomics-and-intrusive-shared-pointer-reference-count?rq=1

Comment: `sub` is a RMW operation.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it prevents any use of `(*x)` to be reordered after the `fetch_sub` (when the reference count could be 0 and use is therefore banned). Possible causes are CPU reordering or compiler reordering. The second question is just the mirror of the release; release protects stores and acquire protects loads.

It may seem that `refcount_fetch_sub(1, memory_order_acq_rel)` works as well, but that protects just the refcount.

Comment: I know both compiler and CPU may reorder commands. However, in this case, the `delete x` command is dependent on the result of the `fetch_sub`. Why there are still possibility that things in `delete x` may be reordered prior to `fetch_sub`?

Comment: In a single-threaded view, reads could be reordered before an unrelated write, i.e. the other members of `x` may already be read to prevent a pipeline stall if the branch succeeds. And that in turn may cause the deletion of an older version of `x` when another thread had updated `x`.

Comment: "_but that protects just the refcount._" What do you mean?

Comment: Surely `memory_order_acq_rel` doesn't just protect the refcount?  Rather the separate barrier is used as an optimization, so that it only uses an acquire barrier if the reference count reaches 0?